# Expected errors in Laravel Dusk

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I am looking for the Laravel Dusk equivalent of

```
this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class);
```

I'm new to using Laravel Dusk (running Laravel 5.7) and cannot find a way to test for an expected error. When I run the following test.

I get the following:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1)
>   Tests\Browser\RegistrationTest::test_user_cannot_register_with_duplicate_email
>   Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email (SQL:
>   insert into "users" ("name", "email", "password", "updated_at",
>   "created_a t") values (Eoj, joe@example.com, 654321, 2018-10-16
>   20:35:09, 2018-10-16 20:35:09))
>
> Caused by PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email
>
> ERRORS! Tests: 4, Assertions: 5, Errors: 1.

```
public function test_user_cannot_register_with_duplicate_email()
{
    User::create([
        'name' => 'Eoj',
        'email' => 'joe@example.com',
        'password' => '654321'

    ]);

    $this->browse(function ($browser) {
        $browser->visit('/') //Go to the homepage
        ->clickLink('Register') //Click the Register link
        ->assertSee('Register') //Make sure the phrase in the argument is on the page
        //Fill the form with these values
        ->value('#name', 'Joe')
            ->value('#email', 'joe@example.com')
            ->value('#password', '123456')
            ->value('#password-confirm', '123456')
            ->click('button[type="submit"]') //Click the submit button on the page
            ->assertPathIs('/register') //Make sure you are still on the register page
            //Make sure you see the phrase in the argument
            ->assertSee("The email has already been taken");
    });

}
```

Obviously I was expecting an error - but can't work out how to tell dusk this.

When I change my code to the following I get a different error:

> 1) >Tests\Browser\RegistrationTest::test_user_cannot_register_with_duplicate_email
>   Did not see expected text [The email has already been taken] within element [body].
>   Failed asserting that false is true.

I am not running any other tests at the moment.

```
    <?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\User;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;


class RegistrationTest extends DuskTestCase

{
    use RefreshDatabase;

protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    foreach (static::$browsers as $browser) {
        $browser->driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();
    }
}

public function test_user_cannot_register_with_duplicate_email()
{
    User::create([
        'name' => 'Eoj',
        'email' => 'someone@example.com',
        'password' => '654321'

    ]);

    $this->browse(function ($browser) {
        $browser->visit('/') //Go to the homepage
        ->clickLink('Register') //Click the Register link
        ->assertSee('Register') //Make sure the phrase in the argument is on the page
        //Fill the form with these values
        ->value('#name', 'Joe')
            ->value('#email', 'someone@example.com')
            ->value('#password', '123456')
            ->value('#password-confirm', '123456')
            ->click('button[type="submit"]') //Click the submit button on the page
            ->assertPathIs('/register') //Make sure you are still on the register page
            //Make sure you see the phrase in the argument
            ->assertSee("The email has already been taken");
    });

}
```

}

Comment: It seems that you have a problem with your code that register user, not the test. You may want to share the controller/model code that saves the user.

Comment: It's the out of the box Laravel  Auth/RegisterController.php that you get after running make:auth. When I have tested it in the browser it works as expected (i.e. doesn't allow you to register a user when the email already exists in database). I should also add the test for registering a new unique user works as expected.

Comment: Do you already have an email `joe@example.com` in your database? You may need to use `RefreshDatabase` trait.

Comment: Yes - it is created in the test. The point of the test is to make sure the user cannot be duplicated... which it can't.

Comment: The problem is within the test not the code. As I said I am new to Laravel Dusk so unsure of the way to test for expected exceptions/errors

Comment: It seems that `User::create([..])` in your test is the one throwing this error. Change the e-mail to a totally different one and try again.

Comment: I'm sorry Felippe Duarte I think you have misunderstood the point of the test.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to say. Your test is trying to insert an already duplicated email. That's why you have this error. Change this e-mail to a different one, both in `User::create` and in `->value('#email', '...')`

Comment: @TriciaCuninghame, I think Felippe Duarte is correct. If you read the error message, it mentions the user with password `654321` is a duplicate. This is the same password you're using in your `User::create()` statement. It's not the password you're using in your test user.

Comment: I know it is a duplicate user - that is the whole point of the test!! How can I test that my app will not create a duplicate user - without first adding a user to the database??

Comment: This is a question about how to expect errors in Laravel Dusk similar to the this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class); in phpunit

Comment: @TriciaCuninghame, you're calling `User::create()` to initially insert what you think is a unique user, to then force the duplicate error when you attempt to register another user with the same email in your test. But the **original call** to `User::create()` is the source of the error based on the insert statement in error message you've posted. For the three seconds it'll take, perhaps you can try Felippe's suggestion, and change the email addresses?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the error:

> Tests\Browser\RegistrationTest::test_user_cannot_register_with_duplicate_email Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email (SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "email", "password", "updated_at", "created_a t") values (Eoj, joe@example.com, 654321, 2018-10-16 20:35:09, 2018-10-16 20:35:09))

The values are exactly the ones that you are trying to insert here:

```
User::create([
    'name' => 'Eoj',
    'email' => 'joe@example.com',
    'password' => '654321'
]);
```

So, you can change this e-mail to a different one:

```
User::create([
    'name' => 'Eoj',
    'email' => 'someone@example.com',
    'password' => '654321'
]);
```

And again here to the test makes sense:

```
->value('#email', 'someone@example.com')
```

This way, the email will not be duplicated, because at some point you already have a "joe@example.com".

A good practice is to reset the database before the tests.

In `tests/TestCase.php` you may have something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase; //<--HERE

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase; //<--HERE
```

And your test must extend this class:

```
use Tests\TestCase; //<--HERE
class MyTest extends TestCase { //<--HERE
```

That way the data you be reseted, avoiding the duplicate e-mail issue in the subsequent tests.

Comment: I'm sorry Fellipe but you have completely misunderstood the whole point of the test I am running.  I am trying to check that a DUPLICATE user cannot be created - therefore there needs to be a duplicate record in the database!  I am already using RefreshDatabase.

Comment: Did you read what I posted? You are already inserting, manually, a duplicate entry. Did you even tried to do what I told?

Comment: Doing what you said would create a new user... That is NOT what I want to do!!

Comment: This is a question about how to expect errors in Laravel Dusk similar to the this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class); in phpunit

Comment: Let's think about this. The point of your test is to check if, when trying to register a duplicated email, the app should return with "The email has already been taken". So, first you register an email, manually, then you force the second register. The point is that your first register (`create`) is already duplicated. That's why you need to change this email.

Comment: Ok I have done it - getting a different error now...have updated initial question with code

Comment: Ok but you need to replace the email in your test too.

Comment: OK - but now I am just back with the same errors I started with - I am not running any other tests and using sqlite :memory: database so there is nowhere else for the duplicate to be coming from??

Comment: Did you add the RefreshDatabase?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you not waiting answer from server (you are submitting form via js, right?), and assertion fires too early. Just use `waitFor` or `waitForText` in these type of scenarios.